# Pre commit hook for eslint and vue

Tags: git, vue.js, eslint, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

I am using [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/) for several hooks within a multi language project. All my existing hooks are working. I am now trying to get a `eslint` hook setup that will include `Vue 2` files.

Here's my `.pre-commit-config.yaml` for the `eslint` section:

```yaml
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-eslint
    rev: 'v7.18.0'
    hooks:
    -   id: eslint
        types_or: [javascript, jsx, ts, tsx, vue]
        additional_dependencies:
        -   eslint-plugin-vue@v7.5.0
```

This works for javascript files but completely ignores the Vue 2 files. I have setup the above config based on this:
[Eslint for vue](https://eslint.vuejs.org/) and [pre-commit eslint](https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-eslint).

I have tried adding the following `.eslintrc` file in the root of the project which hasn't helped:

```js
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/recommended'
  ]
}
```

The Vue files are completely ignored.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [base configuration at that version](https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-eslint/blob/v7.18.0/.pre-commit-hooks.yaml#L5) specifies `types: [javascript]`

when folded together with your configuration this sets:

```yaml
types: [javascript]
types_or: [javascript, jsx, ts, tsx, vue]
```

from [the documentation](https://pre-commit.com/#filtering-files-with-types):

> types, types_or, and files are evaluated together with AND when filtering. Tags within types are also evaluated using AND.
>
> new in 2.9.0: Tags within types_or are evaluated using OR.

Putting that together (with a bit of set notation), you're requesting `{javascript} & {javascript, jsx, ts, tsx, vue}` -- simplified: `{javascript}`

the [README of mirrors-eslint](https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-eslint#using-eslint-with-pre-commit) tells you what to do here, you need to override `types` back to the default `[file]` before applying additional filtering:

```yaml
    -   id: eslint
        types: [file]
        types_or: [javascript, jsx, ts, tsx, vue]
```

---

disclaimer: I'm the creator of pre-commit, in the future please don't post your question to *both* the issue tracker and stackoverflow, thanks!